# Grep using list of terms, display line for every match

Tags: grep

Given a file containing search terms;

```
> cat words.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

And a list of sentences to search against;

```
> cat sent.txt
aaa is 1
bbb is 2
ccc is 3
aaa and bbb is 4
aaa and ccc is 5
```

I want to get a list of lines that match any one of the search terms, whereby one line is displayed for each occurrence of the search term. For example, the above would return;

```
> # Some Command
aaa is 1
bbb is 2
ccc is 3
aaa and bbb is 4 # matches 'aaa'
aaa and bbb is 4 # matches 'bbb'
aaa and ccc is 5 # matches 'aaa'
aaa and ccc is 5 # matches 'ccc'
```

Looking at the `grep` documentation, I think I am part of the way using `-o`;

```
> cat sent.txt | grep -f words.txt -o
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
bbb
aaa
ccc
```

which shows the search term matching each sentence. However is it possible to ensure the sentences are returned instead, without having to loop over each search term?

Comment: what happens when u remove `-o` doesn't it remove all the rows matching the input?

Comment: `while read line ;do grep "$line" sent.txt ;done <words.txt `   ???

Comment: Removing -o returns matches, but it does not return duplicates. @soFan - this works, but is essentially a loop over search terms